# Get the Last page in an odata Query

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata

How could one get the last page of data using skip/take/inlinecount in a single odata query (Wcf Data Services)?

Fx.. With page size 25...

```
http://server:8000/Html5Controls/Services/SampleDBService.svc/Offices?$format=json&$top=25&$skip=0&$orderby=city
```

Would get the first page. Is there a way to combine the count to get the last page in a single query?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do that currently. (You would need a way to reference the total count inside the query for that, but such a function doesn't exist). You could do it in two queries: request the first page with inline count, take that count and compute the $skip value for the last page and request that.

Comment: Yes, That is what i did for now. I understand one way to do it in the database level is to sort backwards and then get the top 25 (pagesize). Then you resort it forwards in an outer query. Was wondering if there might be a way to do something that in an odata query.